# How do I convert this groovy class and run it in Jenkins as a library?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I have this groovy class that has a main method and some other methods.

```
public class secrets {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String secretName = args[0]; 
        String secretType = args[1];  //username, password or b64_authkey

        SecretsManagerClient sm = SecretsManagerClient.builder()
                .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
                .build();

        getSecret(sm, secretName, secretType);
        sm.close();

    }
    public static String getSecret(SecretsManagerClient sm,String secretName, String secretType){
  .......
```

When trying to run this in Jenkins I get the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.dev.libs.secrets.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String,) values: [secret, username]
```

I know I need a `call` function, but I'm not sure on how to use it in this context. How can I convert this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do something with the resulting String object from `getSecret` method. I further assume, that you
have already put your `secrets.groovy` file in a shared library (identified by the name `test-library` in my example)
and have the correct `@Library` annotation in your build script.

*Note:* I had to "mock" some of the objects to test my code. So you can basically ignore the first few code snippets if
you like.

### Jenkins shared library code

#### Mock file for `vars/Region.groovy`

```java
enum Region {
    EU_WEST_1
}
```

#### Mock file for `vars/SecretsManagerClient.groovy`

```java
class SecretsManagerClient {
    static SecretsManagerClientBuilder builder() {
        new SecretsManagerClientBuilder()
    }

    def close() {
    }

    static class SecretsManagerClientBuilder {
        SecretsManagerClientBuilder region(Region region) {
            this
        }

        SecretsManagerClient build() {
            new SecretsManagerClient()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Code example for `vars/secrets.goovy`

```
// probably some import for SecretsManagerClient and Region

//public class secrets {

def call(String secretName, String secretType) {
    SecretsManagerClient sm = SecretsManagerClient.builder()
            .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
            .build();

    try {
        return getSecret(sm, secretName, secretType);
    } finally {
        sm.close();
    }
}

static String getSecret(SecretsManagerClient sm, String secretName, String secretType) {
    "secret"
}

//}
```

### Jenkins pipeline build script

I have used a very simple build script calling the build step and echoing the result from `getSecret` method.

```
// import library named "test-library" in settings (mind the underscore at the end!)
@Library('test-library')_

// run on master node (or any other label you might choose)
node('master') {
  // create a stage
  stage('Get secret from new step') {
    // run our custom build step named "secrets", which will use "call" function to call "getSecret"  
    def theSecret = secrets "name", "type"
    // print result
    sh "echo ${theSecret}"
  }
}
```

### Output

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Test-Job
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Get secret from new step)
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo secret
secret
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Comment: hey thanks for that @ Sebastian Westemeyer , i managed to pretty much copy that code word for word and have got this error ```java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Method 'software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.SecretsManagerClientBuilder software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.SecretsManagerClient.builder()' must be InterfaceMethodref constant ```. Any ideas on how to get round this?

Comment: is the ```this``` in vars/SecretsManagerClient.groovy a syntax error? as it not pointing to anything

Comment: @TheSuperDoughnut The `this` in my `SecretsManagerClient` mock implementation is necessary for the code in `secrets` to work. It is a common practice in "Builder" objects to return the builder object itself in setter methods, see a Java example [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/#implementation). I will have a look into why the error message might occur tonight.

Comment: @TheSuperDoughnut unfortunately I don't have the dependencies in my Jenkins installation, so I can not reproduce your problem. BTW, what is it you are trying to achieve? Is it possible to use some kind of AWS plugin to get the secrects by using a credentialsmanager mechanism supported by Jenkins pipelines?